# Lab code logical error, C program beginner

Tags: c, loops

I have made a program that my professor wants me to make specially how she wants it, however the output is not the same as the correct output.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 16

int xchg(int *a, int *b);

int main (){

    int i, j, k, count;
    int Num[N] = {7, 1, 993, -5, 0, 16, -451, 12, 89,28, 77, 384, -2, 38, -17, 201};

    for(i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j <= N; j++){
        count += xchg(&Num[i], &Num[j]);
        }
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++){
            if(k <= 15){
                printf("%d ", Num[k]);
            }
            else
                printf("%d", Num[k]);
            }
    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("total exchanges: %d\n", count);

}

int xchg(int *a, int *b){

    int c;

    if ( *a > *b )
        c = 1;

    else 
        c = 0;

return c;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
7 1 993 -5 0 16 -451 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201 
total exchanges: 1
```

Here is the correct output:

```
-451 7 993 1 0 16 -5 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -17 201
-451 -17 993 7 1 16 0 12 89 28 77 384 -2 38 -5 201
-451 -17 -5 993 7 16 1 12 89 28 77 384 0 38 -2 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 993 16 7 12 89 28 77 384 1 38 0 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 993 16 12 89 28 77 384 7 38 1 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 993 16 89 28 77 384 12 38 7 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 993 89 28 77 384 16 38 12 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 993 89 77 384 28 38 16 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 993 89 384 77 38 28 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 993 384 89 77 38 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 38 993 384 89 77 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 38 77 993 384 89 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 38 77 89 993 384 201
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 38 77 89 201 993 384
-451 -17 -5 -2 0 1 7 12 16 28 38 77 89 201 384 993
total exchanges:51
```

Please help me turn my output into the correct output! I have only been coding for three months, so I apologize for the basic errors.

Comment: Surely `xchg` is supposed to, I don't know, EXCHANGE the values!!!

Comment: @this i'm pretty sure he meant, he has only been learning to program from three months (not specifically on this program). You probably want `sum += xchg(&Num[i], &Num[j]);` The total number of exchanges made. You also probably want to swap the values if you've made an exchange. You should add specifics questions of what you're unclear of.

Comment: @TimothyMurphy Yes exactly, I have only been learning to code for a total of three months, so I know I am not good, if I would receive some help with this maybe I would understand coding a little better, so far to get the correct output for this code has been difficult for me.

Comment: 1) `xchg` must replace the value indicated by the pointer. also this program has an array out-of-range access.

Comment: @ooga Well, judging by the receiving variable `sum` it is supposed to add them together, or subtract, or multiply, or something... . There is a reason for closing questions that aren't specific.

Comment: @this I think the badly named "sum" variable is actually supposed to count the swaps.

Comment: @ooga Right, right, hmmm, let's figure this out... It doesn't pose a valid question, it doesn't describe what the code does.  Close it!

Comment: 2) `count` need initialize with `0`. E.g `int count = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 16

int xchg(int *a, int *b);

int main (void){
    int i, j, k, count = 0;
    int Num[N] = {7, 1, 993, -5, 0, 16, -451, 12, 89,28, 77, 384, -2, 38, -17, 201};

    for(i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
            count += xchg(&Num[i], &Num[j]);
        }
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++){
            if(k < N-1){
                printf("%d ", Num[k]);
            } else {
                printf("%d", Num[k]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("total exchanges: %d\n", count);
}

int xchg(int *a, int *b){
    int s = (*a > *b);

    if(s){
        int t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: nt sure about assigning boolean result to int s. There's no real need to shorten that bit of code is there?

Comment: result of `(*a > *b)` is `int` (`0` or `1`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Are you aware you are decreasing the value of StackOverflow ( making StackOverflow worse ) overall by providing answers to off-topic questions? Why are you doing this?

Comment: I did not think it's off topic. It is a difference of opinion. OP did not know how to swap.

Comment: As you can see the question is now on-hold and thus off-topic. It would be hard to argue that this is a matter of opinion, when it is clearly stated in the rules, and the majority agreed with those rules. All that OP asked was *Please help me turn my output into the correct output!*. You are stating that he didn't know how to swap, but you still provided the entire code. Assuming you believe your statement is true, then why didn't you only provide the code for swapping?

Comment: As already pointed out in the comments, the array out of range access issues were present. Also initializes the problem of variable. But those it considered to be a careless mistake.

Comment: As you are an adept active user, I urge you you to read the rules and then evaluate if your actions are contributing towards or against those rules and the community. By answering questions in pure code without explanations form and answering bad questions, instead of doing the right thing by closing them, you acting directly against what StackOverflow stands for. Most of your answer are such as this one. You are a major influence on Japan StackOverflow. Please help us make it better, not worse.

Comment: I want to to be able to within the range that can be also within the scope of my understanding. Being forced it is very regrettable. ( ; - ; )

Answer (score -1):

You had a few problems in your code.

Generally you should ask specific questions on what your unsure of.

From what you posted. It looks like you want to perform Bubble sort on the your array Num and count the total number of echanges/swaps that occur.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 16

int xchg(int *a, int *b);

int main (){
    int i, j, k, count = 0;  // Initialize count to be 0 -- Number of exchanges
    int Num[N] = {7, 1, 993, -5, 0, 16, -451, 12, 89,28, 77, 384, -2, 38, -17, 201};

    for(i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j <= N; j++){
            count += xchg(&Num[i], &Num[j]); // counters number of swaps and exchanges values as necessary
        }
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++){         // Prints out newest order of array
            if (k < N - 1)
                printf("%d ", Num[k]);
            else
                printf("%d", Num[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("total exchanges: %d\n", count); // Prints total number of exchanges
}

int xchg(int *a, int *b){ // Function to swap values if *a > *b
    if ( *a > *b ){
        int tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```